# Unable to do sum and division in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Here is my mysql query

```
    SELECT IntervalStartTime,IFNULL(SUM(AbandonedCalls),0) AS AbandonedCallSum,SUM(QueueTime) AS QTS,SUM(RingTime) AS RTS,
IFNULL(SUM(AnsweredCalls),0) AS AnsweredCallSum
FROM intervalqueuestatistics
WHERE CallCenterId=17 AND DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%m')=10 AND DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%Y')=2012
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%d');
```

Now i want to calculate a value `(SUM(QueueTime)+SUM(RingTime))/SUM(AnsweredCalls)`

So i modified my query accordingly as below

```
    SELECT IntervalStartTime,IFNULL(SUM(AbandonedCalls),0) AS AbandonedCallSum,SUM(QueueTime) AS QTS,SUM(RingTime) AS RTS,
IFNULL(SUM(AnsweredCalls),0) AS AnsweredCallSum,IFNULL(SUM(QueueTime),0) + IFNULL(SUM(RingTime),0)/IFNULL(SUM(AnsweredCalls),0)
FROM intervalqueuestatistics
WHERE CallCenterId=17 AND DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%m')=10 AND DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%Y')=2012
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(IntervalStartTime,'%d');
```

But when executed it isn't giving me the correct answer.

For example one of the rows returned by this query

```
 QTS    RTS   AnsweredCallSum CalculatedField 
188000  41645        9          192627.222
```

But the CalculatedField is wrong  it should be 25516.11 as per the calculation mentioned above

Comment: Incorrect in what regard? What are you expecting and what is it returning?

Comment: Could you create an example on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my guess:

1. use `IFNULL(..., 1)` so you're never dividing by `0` should a null column exist.
2. Explicitly use parenthesis so order of operations doesn't fail. (You're currently performing `sum1 + (sum2 / sum3)` when I *think* you wanted `(sum1 + sum2) / sum3`). Remember multiplication & division come before addition & subtraction without the parenthesis.

```
( IFNULL(SUM(QueueTime), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(RingTime), 0) )
        / IFNULL(SUM(AnsweredCalls), 1)
```

Comment: dat indeed was the issue,the braces..thnks

Answer (score 1):

If SUM(AnsweredCalls) is 0, you are dividing by 0 and it should not work.

Comment: Indeed, probably want `IFNULL(..., 1)` and default to 1.

Comment: u r rite but i checked with values which are not null and it is there where i'm getting wrong output.I have update with a sample. Have a look